# Is Deism avoda zara?

Tags: gentiles, avodah-zarah, noahidism

Is Deism avoda zara? It would seem that deists, like Muslims, fall into the category of righteous gentiles, Noahidism. Like Islam, Deism only accepts that there is but one God. Famous American founding father and deist Tom Paine explains the tenets of Deism:

> I believe in one God, and no more; and I hope for happiness beyond this life. I believe the equality of man, and I believe that religious duties consist in doing justice, loving mercy, and endeavoring to make our fellow-creatures happy... That the only true religion is deism, by which I then meant and now mean the belief of one God, and an imitation of his moral character, or the practice of what are called moral virtues;⁠—and that it was upon this only (so far as religion is concerned) that I rested all my hopes of happiness hereafter. So say I now⁠—and so help me God.

Tom Paine's formulation of a deist is someone who believes in one God and no more. They rest at God and do not go further in positing a revelation from God. Based on this formulation, are they Noahides?

Comment: I don't think that quote accurately represents the tenets of Deism. Deism is a belief in a supreme entity that doesn't intervene in the proceedings of the world.

Comment: @Harel13 Are you saying Tom Paine wasn't a deist?

Comment: As said above, deism believes that there is a god but that He doesn’t intervene in the world. This is obviously a counter view of Judaism

Comment: @Shmuel no, I'm saying that this particular quote doesn't accurately define Deism. Any member of any religion or school of thought can happen to explain that religion or school of thought poorly. Moreover, I do not know where you took that quote from, so I don't know in what context he said that. Therefore, I cannot make a good judgement of his relation to this statement.

Comment: @CuriousYid Not all deists felt this way. Thomas Jefferson was a deist who believed God is involved in helping people and so did Washington. It is not clear if Paine believed God is distant or immanent.

Comment: Well, in any case, this isn't the best place to debate the theology of the Founding Fathers (except maybe Hamilton). I recommend you define Deism more clearly in your question. So far in your comments you appear to have suggested that some Deists were pretty much monotheists. So define in what way they were different.

Comment: @Harel13 I took it from Paine's book The Age of Reason. You can word-search the quote in this document [here](https://standardebooks.org/ebooks/thomas-paine/the-age-of-reason/text/single-page).

Comment: @Harel13 I understand that deism is a monotheistic religion. Paine is an authority on deism and when he says deists "believe in one God and no more" this implies they are mono theist.

Comment: So why ever do you think there is something problematic or potentially problematic with Deism?

Comment: @Harel13 I am just wondering if they are avoda zara or does the belief in one God makes them righteous gentiles, Noahides?

Comment: @Shmuel so then what do deists believe then?

Comment: @CuriousYid That deists believe in one God, none will dispute. How he acts however is disputed. Some deists like Voltaire believed God is distant. Yet others, like Ben Franklin, felt that God has a hand in human affairs. There's a spectrum just like everything else. There's a spectrum in Judaism (for example) between rationalists and mystics.

Comment: Without properly defining what it means to be a Deist, no one would be able to answer that question. That's why there are debates on whether Christianity is avodah zara or shituf - because there are different ways to define Christian belief.

Comment: @Harel13 based on Tom Paine's formulation, a deist is someone who believes in one God and no more. They rest at God and do not go further in positing a revelation text from God. Based on this are they Noahides?

Comment: Okay, edit that into your question.

Comment: @Harel13 I edited my question. What do you think? Are they Noahides?

Comment: @Shmuel okay so then ppl amongst deists who believe G-d is distant are going against a basic tenet of Judaism. And others, I wouldn’t call them avoda zara

Comment: @CuriousYid So the early American founders were Christian deists. John Adams, Washington, Franklin, and Jefferson were Christian deist who believed God help win the American cause for Independence. Are they Naohides for you?

Comment: @Shmuel well if they’re Christians then no. The question only asked about regular deists

Comment: @CuriousYid They weren't Christians. They were Christian deist who rejected the divinity of Jesus. How about now?

Comment: @CuriousYid What about regular deist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a fundamental distinction between Islam and Deism, that Islam is also trying to worship the one G-d of the universe, just they are doing it in the wrong way. The stories of Islam and Judaism are very much intertwined, and they split of by Yitzchak and Yishmael. In fact, (I heard that) Rav Moshe Shapiro said that one has to treat a praying Muslim like a Jew davening shemonah esrei (in regards to not being able to walk within 4 amos of them) - because they are praying to the one true G-d of the universe, Hashem, the G-d of Avraham avinu - however, there religion is not true, and they are not serving him in the correct way.

That being said, it does not appear that Deism is idolatry, as it does not worship idols - it is just a fake, untrue religion, and total kefira.

Comment: Why is it a fake religion? Deism is more true than Islam. Deist stops at the one God of the universe and does not go further. Islam does go further by adding a Quran. 

Would you say Sikhs are Naohides? They worship one God. Do Sikhs believe in the one true God?

Comment: @Shmuel Rav Tovia Singer says that muslims are benei noach, it's a very interesting question

Comment: @RabbiKaii I know, yes. Rabbi Asher Meza says Christians are Noahides for Christians. But what about deist or Sikhs? A friend of mine who is a rabbi says Sikhs are ok.

Comment: The Rambam has a whole list of beliefs and how they qualify. Deism, like atheism, is not "avodah zarah", but it is heresy for Jews. If your question is how Judaism views deist non-Jews, please refine that and ask it separately.

Comment: @Shmuel Deism isn't more true then Islam - they are both sheker.  By saying 'fake' I meant that the religion, which is what their understanding of G-d is and how they relate to Him and worship him - is fake. It may not be the exact correct verbiage, though.

Comment: @KovyJacob You may be right. I am not sure. It doesn't bother me either way. My point was that deists stop at God while all other religions go further and stipulate a "holy" book. There's nothing wrong with that. Just saying that deist stop at God and go no further. I think Islam is fake, too. But there are "truths" in the Quran. Rav Kook said other religions can teach the truth.

Comment: @Shmuel Well I don't know what you mean 'there is nothing wrong with it' - its sheker, and ideally they would all recognize the one true G-d.

Comment: @KovyJacob They would say they do recognize the one true God. They just think that God did not write a book.

Comment: @KovyJacobn Deism is not a religion but a philosophy.

Comment: @Shmuel I believe they refer to themselves as a religion, or a natural religion.